# how to fix the thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access

Tags: .net, memory, crash, out-of-memory, ram

Last month i was experiencing some issues with games after i installed new RAM. i went from (2x4GB) 3000MhZ to (2x8GB) 3200MhZ and since then i kept getting crashes. Every game that i played crashed after a few minutes and i got this error code:

> The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which
> it does not have the appropriate access

I tried multiple things as checking for memory issues, lowering settings, reinstalling games, checking game files but none had worked..

Answer (score 2):

Now after a very while and researching when nothing can be found on this error on the internet i finally fixed it.

The fix for me was that my processor could only handle 2933Mhz and my new RAM was 3200Mhz. Which could be seen here: [Specs of my Processor](https://tweakers.net/pricewatch/1166767/amd-ryzen-5-2600-wraith-box-boxed/specificaties/) at processor technique it showed: PC4-23466 (DDR4-2933)

I quickly went to my BIOS and limited my RAM speed to 2933Mhz and it has been fixed!

For anyone that has this same error or behaviour try this method because i've seen some people just buy new RAM because of this. This is the only fix on the internet that worked for me and probably as well for other people.

Thank you all for taking your time to read this thread.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your fix. This has sadly not been the fix for me.

Comment: You deserve the biggest round of applause in the world. My CSGO kept crashing with XMP on. I'm running 3600Mhz RAM, however the 3900x Ryzen 9 only supports a max of 3200 according to the website you referenced.

I reduced my multiplier from 36 to 32, so now I'm running 3200mhz... Problem solved.

You... Are my hero